# How to filter an array of objects by another object?

Tags: javascript

Like i have an array of objects:

```
const arr = [
{name: 'Adam', age: 23},
{name: 'Steve', age: 23},
{name: 'Eve', age: 30}
];
```

And i have another object

```
let obj = {age: 23}
```

How can I filter an array so it will be contain just:

```
 [
    {name: 'Adam', age: 23},
    {name: 'Steve', age: 23},
 ];
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Try `arr.filter(a => a.age === obj.age)`

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some [research, search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+filter+an+array+of+objects+by+another+object?+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan I'm struggling to find a dupe target

Comment: `const filterAge = obj.age; const result = arr.filter(({age}) => age ===  filterAge)`

Comment: A more interesting problem would be applying a general filter object with an unknown number unknown keys. So you could have just `age`, just `name` or both in the filter object and an element of `arr` is filtered if it matches the filter in all keys (or maybe just in any one of them?)

Comment: I think @ZAPE wants to filter items which include an object.
If that please do like this.
```var exists = arr.find(function(o){
    return Object.keys(o).some(function(k){
          return !Object.keys(obj).indexOf(k)>-1 || o[k]!=obj1[k];
    });
});```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArray = arr.filter(a => a.age == obj.age);
```